# PowerBI - Adding target ROW into matrix

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have matrix visual and im trying to add a target as ROW in that matrix as the below image:

[image]

Any Ideas how to create this view before the actual values?

I have searched alot to achieve this but couldnt find any helpful results.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code but you may need to revise the data types...

Modelling--> New Table

```
new table = 
UNION(
    'YourTableName'
    , ROW(
        "SLA/KPI", "Target"
        ,"Incoming", "-"
        ,"Completed", "-"
        ,"AHT", "<15 mins"
        ,"QA", ">95%"
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi Umut K.

should i add it as measure? cuz i am trying to add as measure and it shows an error "Each table argument of 'UNION' must have the same number of columns."

Comment: @egflame sorry to mention, add as a new table ``Modelling--> New Table``

Comment: @egflame you may get an error for the data type...